# Aligning top row of a table with the item label in a list

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, lists

I have used the enumerate environment to create a list
in which every item contains a table, created using
the tabular environment. The first row of each table
should be aligned with the item label, (a), (b), etc.
This is not the the case if the table starts with an 
\hline. How can I fix the alignment in such a case?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate} 
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item 
   \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|}
     a & b \\  \hline c & d  \\ \hline
   \end{tabular}
\item 
   \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|} 
     \hline e & f \\ \hline g & h \\ \hline
   \end{tabular}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just had to solve this problem, and "The LaTeX Companion" (second edition) has the answer on page 280. The `[t]` option aligns the tabular to the `\hline` instead of the baseline of the text. The `array` package has the command `\firsthline` which corrects this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate,array} 
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item 
   \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|}
     a & b \\  \hline c & d  \\ \hline
   \end{tabular}
\item 
   \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|} 
     \firsthline e & f \\ \hline g & h \\ \hline
   \end{tabular}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image: firsthline fix]

Answer (score 2):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you will directly have the expected output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{enumerate} 
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item 
   \begin{NiceTabular}[t]{|c|c|}
     a & b \\  \hline c & d  \\ \hline
   \end{NiceTabular}
\item 
   \begin{NiceTabular}[t]{|c|c|} 
     \hline e & f \\ \hline g & h \\ \hline
   \end{NiceTabular}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

i don't know what is the cause of your problem, however work around can be use `\fbox` instead top/bottom (and vertical outer lines too) table's `\hline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\newcommand\tabbox[1]{\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}\fbox{#1}} % <-- new

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item
   \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|}
     a & b \\  \hline c & d  \\ \hline
   \end{tabular}
\item
   \tabbox{\begin{tabular}[t]{c|c} % <-- new
            e & f \\ \hline g & h \\
           \end{tabular}}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Elegant workaround, just what I needed! Thanks! Minor remark: since the \fbox creates the outer box, the vertical line specification for the tabular environement can be simplified from {|c|c|} to {c|c}, else the outer vertical lines are printed 'twice' and  might look thicker than the other lines (at least on my monitor).

Comment: you have right. better is delete the outer vertical lines. the answer is now corrected accordingly.